# How do I group the pay amounts to give an up to date amount for each employee?

Tags: ms-access

```
SELECT Employee.EmployeeID, Employee.LastName, Employee.FirstName, (PayRecord.Quantity * PayClass.PayRate) AS Up-to-date
FROM Employee, PayRecord, PayClass
WHERE PayRecord.EmployeeID = Employee.EmployeeID and
PayRecord.PayClassID= PayClass.PayClassID
Group By Employee.EmployeeID;
```

I want to keep an up to date query to keep track of pay.
it will give the error that something is not part of the aggregate function

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Employee.EmployeeID, Employee.LastName, Employee.FirstName, max(PayRecord.Quantity) * max(PayClass.PayRate) AS Up-to-date
FROM Employee
JOIN PayRecord ON PayRecord.EmployeeID = Employee.EmployeeID
JOIN PayClass ON PayRecord.PayClassID= PayClass.PayClassID
GROUP BY Employee.EmployeeID, Employee.LastName, Employee.FirstName;
```

The rule to remember is that, whenever you GROUP BY, every column you SELECT must be either in the GROUP BY clause or in an aggregate function.  I picked "max", but I am not sure what aggregate you really want.

This is the standard SQL answer; the Access answer could be slightly different, but I doubt it.

Comment: OK, fixed it for you.

Comment: I don't think max would work in my case since every time I add a record  in PayRecord a worker can have different pay rates on different days times the quantity

Comment: Well, we have to aggregate somehow--or maybe you want to add PayRecord.Quantity and PayClass.PayRate to your group by so that you can see multiple results if you have different quantities  or pay rates?

Answer (score 0):

You should learn to use explicit `join` syntax.

Your specific problem is the presence of column in the `select` list that are not in aggregation functions nor in the `group by`.  An easy way to fix this is by adding them to the `group by`.  However, I think the calculation should be a `SUM()`.  The query should look more like:

```
SELECT e.EmployeeID, e.LastName, e.FirstName, SUM(pr.Quantity * pc.PayRate) AS UpToDate
FROM (Employee as e INNER JOIN
      PayRecord as pr
      ON pr.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID) INNER JOIN
     PayClass pc
     ON pr.PayClassID = pc.PayClassID
Group By e.EmployeeID, e.LastName, e.FirstName;
```

Note that the alias `Up-to-date` is not a valid column name.  I removed the hyphens.  You could also do `[up-to-date]`, but why use square braces if you don't need to.

Comment: is there a reason there is two employeeID's @Gordon Linoff

Comment: @44hz . . . I must've copied it over again.

Comment: FYI, probably shouldn't use parentheses in your joins--but otherwise looks good.

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski . . . I certainly would not use parentheses in my joins, except MS Access requires them.  Personally, I think they are an abomination, but they are still necessary.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I'm glad you know Access peculiarities so well; someone has to.